# Spacing between bars in Bar Graph in Android using GraphView Library

Tags: android, graph, spacing, android-graphview

I am using GraphView Lib for generating runtime Bar graph
What i have achieved is in Snap1--[image: This is what i achieved so far]

Whereas what i required is in ReqSnap1-[image: VerticalBar Bar Graph with Some space between bars]
ReqSnap2[image: Horizontal Graph with Some space between bars]--

Any help would be great 
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is a known bug in graphview. will be fixed in the next few days. https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/14

Comment: Ok Sir, Please let me know if this bug is being fixed. Thanks for the response.

Comment: please try with current version from github

Comment: What have u solved in new version orientation or the spacing.

Comment: only spacing. orientation will not be changed in the next future ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code create spacing between bars (Kotlin)

```
barGraphSeries.spacing = 15
```

This code create spacing between bars (Java)

```
barGraphSeries.setSpacing(15)
```